# Should multi threading be used to download lots of images?

Tags: java, multithreading, download

I want to download several images(minimum 100,000). I have the URLs of these images.

Should I used multithreading to download these images? Will that be of any significant benefit?

I have a text file with URLs to these 100,1000 images. I was thinking I'll make 100 threads and assign 1000 Urls to each thread.

Will that help me download the stuff faster?  on that note, when is it suitable to use multithreading ?

Comment: It seems likely that you would hit your bandwidth limit long before this would make any difference - if indeed it would make a difference at all.

Comment: no I will not ... each images is around 20 kb in size. 20*100 threads = 2000 kb  = 2MB of data at any given time ...which is not much

Comment: Try it - knock up a client that just downloads some images serially and time it.  Run two copies of the app that download different sets of images, (which effectively means two download threads), and see if it takes twice as long, or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your download will be much faster when using multi-threading as you plan to do. This is because during the process of downloading there are short delays in which resources (CPU, network, etc.) go unused. Other threads can fill that gaps to fully utilize your resources. Note that, in your situation the bottle neck may be the servers form where you download. If it is a single one, then it might limit the number of concurrent downloads per client. You may want to vary the number of threads to find out the optimum.

From the point of view of resoure usage time gaps, multi-threading is generally suitable for doing processes which cause such delays of resource usage on ALL (beware "bottle necks") involved time-multi-plexed resources (CPU, network, hard-disk etc.). However, multi-threading comes at the cost of

- extra resource management, which will over-compensate the benefits if too many threads are used, i.e. there is an optimum speed-up for any given resource setup.
- extra complexity for thread-safe programming - and eventually for preventing temporary over-usage of resources ("traffic jams"). Because of that complexity increase, if you view multi-threading as optimization then use it only if you must. Remember "*Premature optimization is the source of all evil.*" - Donald Knuth

Comment: You are right ...multithreading is better...i tried it out. Also , there are a lot of network delays involved...so undoubtedly multithreading is better...